# How to bind the click event for only once WHEN checked on radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 html radio button which is bellow :

```
<div class='radio'>
    <label><input type='radio' name='delivery_option' id='pickup'><strong>PICKUP</strong></label>
</div>
<div class='radio'>
    <label><input type='radio' name='delivery_option' id='delivery'><strong>DELIVERY</strong></label>
</div>
<div>
    <tr>
        <td id="total">$30</td>
    </tr> 
</div>
```

Now I am adding 2 when **DELIVERY** option is checked and deducting 2 when **PICKUP** option is choose.

**What is happening now :**

For e.g :

Total price $30

I choose DELIVERY, So total is now : $32
I choose PICKUP, So total is now : $30

again...

I choose DELIVERY, So total is now : $32
I choose PICKUP, So total is now : $30

But at this stage..If I click PICKUP again it's deducting 2 from $30, So total $28 which **I don't want.** It's should be **REMAIN $30** I know It's happening because of my click event.

Is there any way so that I can bind the click event for only once when checked on radio button ?

**jQuery Code :**

```
$("#pickup").bind('click', function() {
        $("#delivery_result2_address").show();
        $("#delivery_result2").hide();
        $("#delivery_charge").hide();       
        var total = parseInt( $("#total").text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""));        
        var total =  total - 2;        
        $("#total").text("$"+total);
    });

    $("#delivery").bind('click', function() {
        $("#delivery_charge").show();
        var total = parseInt( $("#total").text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""));
        var total =  total + 2;        
        $("#total").text("$"+total);
        $("#delivery_result2").show();
        $("#delivery_result2_address").hide();    
    });
```

Comment: Use `change` event instead but anyway you are overcomplicating it for sure and btw your HTML markup is invalid, a `tr` child of `div`???

Comment: OOOPS! That's really a simple solution. Thanks @Wolff.

Comment: Just testing purpose I set the html but can you tell me where I overcomplicating on jQuery ?

Comment: I meant as e.g using data-* attribute: https://jsfiddle.net/wb5426xc/

Comment: I got it. Thank You.